# Spree Ruby on rails query

Tags: ruby, activerecord, spree, ransack

Trying to learn Ruby and Spree

I've got a query in my controller that's running fine:

```
@products = Spree::LineItem.select("spree_line_items.id, 
spree_variants.sku, spree_products.name, spree_line_items.quantity")
.joins(:order).joins(:variant).joins(:product)
.where(spree_orders: {state: 'complete', shipment_state: 'ready'})
```

When I run the query in my view

```
<% @products.each do |lineItem| %>
<%= lineItem.id %><br>
<% end %>
```

This works fine and spits out all of the ID's but I'm wanting to output the other bits, Sku, Name and Quantity which are all from other tables. How do I bring them in here?

If I reference them the same as the ID I get a DelegationError.

Comment: What is `@ordersNew`? You haven't show us how this is defined, so I don't know why the error is occurring. As a side note, it is [ruby convention](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) to use `snake_case` not `camelCase` for variable names.

Comment: That was just a typo, should be products. Updated now

Comment: Is there a good reason for your `select` query? Why not just return the whole record? Then you can just do e.g. `product.variant.sku` .... moreover, *what exactly is the error you're seeing*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your query, you can do

```
@products = Spree::LineItem.select("spree_line_items.id, 
spree_variants.sku AS variant_sku,
spree_products.name as product_name,
spree_line_items.quantity as quantity")
.joins(:order).joins(:variant).joins(:product)
.where(spree_orders: {state: 'complete', shipment_state: 'ready'})
```

Then access sku as `lineItem.variant_sku`, name as `lineItem.product_name` and quantity as `lineItem.quantity`.

But the appropriate way to achieve this is

```
Spree::LineItem.joins(:order).includes(variant: :product)
.where(spree_orders: {state: 'complete', shipment_state: 'ready'})
```

And access attributes as `lineItem.sku`, `lineItem.name`, `lineItem.quantity`

We can do this because `sku` and `name` are delegated to `variant` in `line_item` model. This the same reason that you are getting DelegationError.